# Efficient bitwise OR of two Byte[Array]

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, arrays, bitwise-operators

I need to bitor 2 very large (>1GB) ByteArray in Spark (so using Scala).

I'm look for the most efficient way (in term of speed and memory), which means I don't want to use stuff like the 'zip' method that will transform my array to a list.

For now, I'm using the following method but I would like to know if some of you have other idea...

```
def bitor(x: Array[Byte], y: Array[Byte]) : Array[Byte] = {
  for(i <- 0 to x.size) {
    x(i) = (x(i) | y(i)).toByte
  }
  return x
}
```

Should I go through JNI and compute it in native C ?

Comment: If efficiency is your concern, why do you have >2GB loaded into memory in the first place?

Comment: I should probably have mentionned it but this is executed on cluster nodes with a lot of RAM (using Spark).

Comment: Use a while loop, it will be faster than the map that the `for` de-sugars to.

Comment: How are these arrays represented in your spark application? Do you have `RDD[Array[Byte]]` which you want to reduce or you have two `RDD[Byte]`?

Comment: @m-z, can you explain what's bad about having large arrays of primitives in memory? As far as I know, they don't put any more load on garbage collector than single object.

Comment: @Aivean I have RDD[Array[Byte]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code that use `foreach` desugars into equivalent of this java code:

```
public final class _$$anon$1$$anonfun$bitor$1 extends AbstractFunction1$mcVI$sp implements Serializable {
    private final byte[] x$1;
    private final byte[] y$1;

    public _$$anon$1$$anonfun$bitor$1(byte[] x$1, byte[] y$1) {
        this.x$1 = x$1;
        this.y$1 = y$1;
    }

    @Override
    public final void apply(final int i) {
        this.apply$mcVI$sp(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void apply$mcVI$sp(final int i) {
        this.x$1[i] |= this.y$1[i];
    }
}


private byte[] bitor(final byte[] x, final byte[] y) {
    RichInt.to$extension0(Predef.intWrapper(0), Predef.byteArrayOps(x).size())
            .foreach(new _$$anon$1$$anonfun$bitor$1(x, y));
    return x;
}
```

However, if you replace `for` comprehension with `while`, things change:

```
def bitor(x: Array[Byte], y: Array[Byte]) : Array[Byte] = {
  var i = 0
  while (i < x.length) {
    x(i) = (x(i) | y(i)).toByte
    i += 1
  }

  x
}
```

Is transpiled to:

```
private byte[] bitor(final byte[] x, final byte[] y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
        x[i] |= y[i];
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Do you think the compiler is then able to vectorize the for-loop ?

Comment: @elldekaa, I'm not sure that JIT currently supports vectorization. If you want to get every bit of performance, go with JNI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing your code is running in a distributed environment. If that, I think the best option is to use [parallel collections API](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html)

A parallel collection performs the task using the multi core hardware of your machines and offers a simple and transparent effort for the developer.

I think the major advantage of this approach is that your code will be ready if you add more hardware to your cloud service and you won't need to change anything.

I ran some test of your code vs a parallel implementation. *Note that I did these tests on my personal computer using Scala REPL*

```
import scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray
import scala.util.Random

// prepare arrays
val rnd = Random

// parallel arrays
val pArr1 = ParArray.tabulate(20000)(x => rnd.nextInt(100).toByte)
val pArr2 = ParArray.tabulate(20000)(x => rnd.nextInt(100).toByte)

// common arrays
val arr1 = pArr1.toArray
val arr2 = pArr2.toArray

println(pArr1)
println(pArr2)

println(arr1)
println(arr2)

println("Variables loaded")

// define parallel task
def parallel(arr1: ParArray[Byte], arr2: ParArray[Byte]): Unit = {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis
  val r = (arr1 zip arr2).map(x => x._1 | x._2)
  //println(r)
  println(s"Execution time: ${System.currentTimeMillis - start}")
}

// define single thread task
def bitor(x: Array[Byte], y: Array[Byte]): Unit = {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis
  for (i <- 0 until x.size) {
    x(i) = (x(i) | y(i)).toByte
  }
  //x.foreach(println)
  println(s"Execution time: ${System.currentTimeMillis - start}")
  //  return x
}

println("functions defined")
```

I'm generating 20 000 random numbers between 1 to 100 and converting them into bytes.

After that, I executed 20 times each method (parallel and single thread) and the execution was as follows:

```
> (1 to 20).foreach(x => parallel(pArr1, pArr2))


// parallel method (in milliseconds)
1)  Execution time: 10
2)  Execution time: 3
3)  Execution time: 6
4)  Execution time: 4
5)  Execution time: 29
6)  Execution time: 4
7)  Execution time: 4
8)  Execution time: 3
9)  Execution time: 3
10) Execution time: 6
11) Execution time: 1
12) Execution time: 2
13) Execution time: 1
14) Execution time: 1
15) Execution time: 4
16) Execution time: 1
17) Execution time: 1
18) Execution time: 2
19) Execution time: 1
20) Execution time: 1

Avg(11 to 20) = 1.5 milliseconds
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------

```
(1 to 20).foreach(x => bitor(arr1, arr2))

// bitor method (in milliseconds)
1)  Execution time: 1
2)  Execution time: 0
3)  Execution time: 0
4)  Execution time: 1
5)  Execution time: 0
6)  Execution time: 0
7)  Execution time: 1
8)  Execution time: 0
9)  Execution time: 0
10) Execution time: 3
11) Execution time: 0
12) Execution time: 0
13) Execution time: 0
14) Execution time: 0
15) Execution time: 2
16) Execution time: 0
17) Execution time: 3
18) Execution time: 0
19) Execution time: 1
20) Execution time: 0

Avg(11 to 20) = 0.6 milliseconds
```

I dropped the first ten executions because of JIT compiler preparation. [See more here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/performance)

As you can see **bitor** method is a little bit faster than parallel, I'm not sure if the **parallel** method would be optimized with a better solution for Parallel API, but I think in a distributed cloud environment **parallel** method should be faster than **bitor**.

Comment: Using parallel collections inside of Spark makes no sense. Spark most probably already utilizes all available cores and creating additional concurrency most probably will negatively affect performance.